# How to access web page hierarchy inside a application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

Trying to figure out how to programmatically access the web pages in the application. Just something simple like a list of them would be awesome. I know I can create a list but I was wondering if there was something that could 'look' at the pages and add a new one to the list if you make a new page for the application.

Example with 7 pages:

```
 Error
 Default
 Login
 Content
 Users
 ContactUs
 Admin
```

I am half awake so I may be a little unclear. Maybe puting it all in a single question will be easier.

How do you autogenerate a list of all webpages in your current application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a traditional ASP.Net application, you can simply find all of the .aspx files, like this:

```
Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/"), "*.aspx", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Note that this will return full filepaths; you can call [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) to get the names.